# Getting window style

Tags: c++, window-style

I'm trying to check if a window has a certain style using GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE) but that gives me a LONG type of variable. how would you check for a specific style from that say a const value type 'WS_CAPTION'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use the bitwise & operator to compare with that long type,

example

```
if (szLng & WS_CAPTION){
    // that window has caption
}
```

Comment: Its not the logical, but the *bitwise* AND operator.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the window styles WS_ are single-bit values;
that is each of them occupies only one bit in dwStyles.

Here `dwStyles` can be obtained from: `DWORD dwStyles = CWnd::GetStyle();`

But some of the WS_ styles, such as `WS_CAPTION`, `WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW`,
`WS_POPUPWINDOW`, combine a few single-bit styles.

The test code below is OK for single-bit window styles
but not `OK` for combined styles.

```
DWORD dwSomeStyle = WS_... ;
BOOL bSomeStyleIsPresentForThisWnd;

if (dwStyles & dwSomeStyle)
  bSomeStyleIsPresentForThisWnd = TRUE;
else
  bSomeStyleIsPresentForThisWnd = FALSE;
```